waveform visualization howler.js and react-h5-audio-player
I am trying to use the code below to generate a sound waveform, however, there are some problems with my solution
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Download, Music } from 'lucide-react';
import { Skeleton } from "../../components/ui/skeleton";
import AudioPlayer from 'react-h5-audio-player';
import 'react-h5-audio-player/lib/styles.css';

const HandlePlayer = ({ audioURL, isLoading, playAudio, pauseAudio, canvasRef }: any) => {

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <div className="w-full max-w-3xl mx-auto mt-8 p-6  rounded-lg mt-[14%] border border-black h-[max-content]">
        <Skeleton className="w-full h-32 mb-4" />
        <Skeleton className="w-full h-16 mb-4" />
        <Skeleton className="w-32 h-10" />
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className="w-full max-w-3xl h-[max-content] mt-[14%] mx-auto mt-8 p-6 border border-black rounded-lg transition-all duration-300 hover:shadow-lg">
      {audioURL ? (
        <>
          <canvas ref={canvasRef} width="600" height="128" className="w-full h-32 rounded-md mb-4 bg-blue-100" />
          <div className="mb-4">
            <AudioPlayer
              src={audioURL}
              autoPlay={false}
              onPlay={playAudio} //comment out
              onPause={pauseAudio} // comment out
              showDownloadProgress={true}
              showFilledVolume={false}
              // You can add custom styling to AudioPlayer here if it accepts className prop
              className="w-full"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="flex justify-end">
            <a
              href={audioURL}
              download="myaudio.mp3"
              className="flex items-center px-4 py-2 bg-purple-500 text-white rounded-md hover:bg-purple-600 transition-colors duration-200"
            >
              <Download size={20} className="mr-2" />
              Download file
            </a>
          </div>
        </>
      ) : (
        <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center h-64 bg-gray-100 rounded-lg">
          skip here
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default HandlePlayer;


The main function is below:
import React, { useState,useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Icon } from '@iconify/react';
import { podcastIcons } from '@/db/data';
import axios from 'axios';
import PlayHandle from './AudioPlayer';




const PlayFile: React.FC = () => {
    const [linkName, setLinkName] = useState<string>(''); // State for link name
    
    
    const [audioURL, setAudioURL] = useState<string | null>(null);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const soundRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
    const [audioURL, setAudioURL] = useState<string | null>(null);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement | null>(null); // Reference to the canvas
    const audioAnalyser = useRef<AnalyserNode | null>(null); // Reference to the audio analyse

    // Add this line to handle the muted state;
    const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false); // State for playback status

    const handleAudio = async (response) => {
    // const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response]));
    const audioBlob = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'audio/mpeg' });
    const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
    setAudioURL(audioUrl); // Set audio URL

    // Check if sound reference exists, if yes, unload it
    if (soundRef.current) {
        soundRef.current.unload();
    }

    // Create a new Howl instance
    soundRef.current = new Howl({
        src: [audioUrl],
        format: ['mp3'], // Adjust based on your audio format
        html5: true, // Use HTML5 Audio for large files
        onload: () => {
            console.log('Audio loaded successfully');
            // soundRef.current?.play(); // Automatical
         const audioNode = soundRef.current?._sounds[0]?._node; // HTMLAudioElement

            if (!audioAnalyser.current) {
                    // Create a new analyser only if it doesn't exist
                    if (audioNode instanceof HTMLAudioElement) {
                        audioAnalyser.current = Howler.ctx.createAnalyser();
                        const soundNode = Howler.ctx.createMediaElementSource(audioNode);
                        soundNode.connect(audioAnalyser.current);
                        audioAnalyser.current.connect(Howler.ctx.destination);

                        // Start visualizing the audio
                        visualize();
                    } else {
                        console.error('Audio node is not defined or not an HTMLAudioElement.');
                    }
                } else {
                    // If audioAnalyser already exists, reconnect
                    console.log("error")
                }
  
    });
};

const playAudio = () => {
    if (Howler.ctx.state == 'suspended') {
        Howler.ctx.resume(); // Resume the audio context if suspended
    }
    soundRef.current?.play(); // Play the audio using Howler
    setIsPlaying(true); // Update state to indicate audio is playing
};

const pauseAudio = () => {
    if (soundRef.current) {
        soundRef.current.pause(); // Pause the audio using Howler
        setIsPlaying(false); // Update state to indicate audio is paused
    }
};

const visualize = () => {
        const canvas = canvasRef.current;
        if (!canvas || !audioAnalyser.current) return;

        const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        const bufferLength = audioAnalyser.current.frequencyBinCount;
        const dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);
        // canvas.style.border = 'none'; // Ensures no border is applied


        const draw = () => {
            audioAnalyser.current.getByteFrequencyData(dataArray);
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // Clear the canvas before each

            const barWidth = (canvas.width / bufferLength) * 10.5;
            //let barHeight;
            let x = 0;
            const centerY = canvas.height /5; // Center y position


            for (let i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) {
               

            const barHeight = dataArray[i] / 8; // Scale down the height for a smoother look

            // Draw the wave form as a line instead of bars
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(x, centerY); // Start from the center of the canvas
            context.lineTo(x, centerY - barHeight); // Draw line to the height of the bar
            context.strokeStyle = `rgb(${barHeight + 80}, 0, 0)`; // Change color based on height
            context.lineWidth = barWidth; // Set line width
            context.stroke();
            x += barWidth + 1; // Move to the next position
            }

            requestAnimationFrame(draw);
        };

        draw();
    };    
    
    const handleSubmit = async (event: React.FormEvent) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('link_name', linkName);
        try {
                        const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/submitform/', formData, {
                            headers: {
                                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                            },
                        });
          await handlingAudio(response)
    };
  
);
return (

        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className=" bg-gradient-to-r  flex-col lg:flex-row lg:space-x-8 p-6 font-sans py-12 px-6">

         
                </div>
                 
                {/* Link Name Input Field */}
                <div className="mb-6">
                    <label className="font-semibold mb-2">Document Link</label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        value={linkName}
                        onChange={(e) => setLinkName(e.target.value)}
                        className="border rounded w-full py-2 px-3"
                        placeholder="Link to file"
                    />
                </div>
                <button className="bg-black text-white py-3 px-8 rounded w-full">
                    submit file
                </button>
           
            {/* Show the audio player and waveform if the audio URL is available */}
            <PlayHandle
                audioURL={audioURL}
                isLoading={isLoading}
                playAudio={playAudio} // comment ot=ut
                pauseAudio={pauseAudio} // comment out
                canvasRef={canvasRef}
            />
        </form>
    );
};

export default PlayFile;



The problem with the curent solution is 2 fold.
In the current configuration the  sound wave form shows  but the audio while playing gives  a  sound effect that is unnatural compared to when I play the audio on my system. I guess this is because I am currently overriding the default play/pause functions in Audio player  by the Howlerjs handler. Am I correctly overriding the play function above and what might be responsible for the unnatural sound effect?
Secondly, without overriding the play function(), the audio sound is natural and as expected but the wave form does not show. My investigation shows that isPlaying is false as seen by HowlerJs, so no wave form to capture. Is there any way to correct this.
In effect, I want the simplest solution/correction to have the corect sound and wave form.
